# Creating a self incrementing function

Tags: python, dictionary, auto-increment

Say I have two dictionary objects like:

```
members = {"member1" : ["PCP1", "PCP2", "PCP3"],
          "member2": ["PCP1", "PCP2", "PCP3"],
          "member3": ["PCP1", "PCP2", "PCP3"],
          "member4": ["PCP1", "PCP2", "PCP4"],
          "member5": ["PCP1", "PCP3", "PCP4"]}

providers = {"PCP1": 2, "PCP2": 1, "PCP3": 2, "PCP4": 1}
```

I have created a function that counts the discrepancies between the requested counts for each provider (PCP) and the actual slots available for each, as seen in `providers`.  The function I have to post here is too long, over 50 lines, to post here but basically it looks at the discrepancy and if its one, it creates a sample_counter and uses that to randomly sample one of the members out of the list of members for that providers.  It should start with the case where there is one discrepancy, such as with "PCP4", only two `members` requested him/her so the function would choose between the two of them and pick one and append to a dictionary of matches and remove them from `members` and that "PCP4" from `providers` since they are now full.  Then for that member which was selected from the random selection, they remain in `members` but now their list of PCPs only contains the other providers since "PCP4" was deleted from their selection list.

The outcome would look like this for example, if "member4" was not selected from the random.sample and so was matched and now out of the pool:

```
members = {"member1" : ["PCP1", "PCP2", "PCP3"],
          "member2": ["PCP1", "PCP2", "PCP3"],
          "member3": ["PCP1", "PCP2", "PCP3"],,
          "member5": ["PCP1", "PCP3"]}

providers = {"PCP1": 2, "PCP2": 1, "PCP3": 2}

matches = {"member4" : "PCP4"}
```

I have created a function, which I will share if requested, that does a random selection when there is just one discrepancy between the counts and so just 1 sample, but I want something where it keeps going up, like selecting two where the difference is two, and so on.  I could write the same function basically over and over just doing 2, and then 3, 4, and so on until there are no more "members" in `members`. but was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: We don't need (or want) to see your function. Write a small example function that exhibits the same problem and add that to you question (aka [mre]).

Comment: @martineau Well, sorry the function I wrote is the minimal reproducible example that I can write. If I could write it more simply in less lines, I would have.

Comment: I doubt that. Regardless, here's a hint that might help: Functions are first class objects in Python, and can have named attributes assigned to them. I.e. `func.count = 42`.

Comment: Thanks.  42 would be the number of times to iterate the function?

Comment: It's a random number I picked and could be anything you want it to be. You can also make it a `list` or something else (it doesn't have to be an integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could help a lot if you post your function, but with the infos you give I think a solution could be:

Let's say you use the function: `difference_function`
And the two dictionnaries you detailed are parameters for this function.

Then you could just iterae over the dictionnary : `members.items()` and store in another dictionnary the discrepancy for each key of `members`. Then just iterate on a list which is : `[1, 2, .... size(members)]` and use each column of this list as a key for the dictionnary of discrepancies.

In python code that could be (not sure of the size/len of a dict):

```
dict_discrepancies={}
for key, el in members.items():
    dict_discrepancies[difference_function(el)]=key

#To access to the different discrepancies by order
for i in range(0, len(members)):
    #This is the member with i discrepancy
    members[dict_discrepancies[i]]
```